# How to create an extension for Google Chrome that changes the URL

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, url, google-chrome-extension, tabs

I have a Chrome tab with an URL. Using a Chrome extension, I need to get that URL, change it a bit, and open the resulting URL in a new Chrome tab.

That should be triggered from a context menu or by clicking a button on Chrome's toolbar.

For example, if the original URL is

```
https://site_name/new-article_owner/section-number/
```

I want the extension to remove from the original URL `new-`, `_owner` and `section-`, so the resulting URL should be:

```
https://site_name/article/number/
```

I would appreciate a step by step explanation and references to the docs as I'm really inexperienced with Chrome extensions.

Comment: Which don't you know? How to replace strings? How to open a new tab? How to package a chrome extensions? All of these are very separate questions and easy to find on Google.

Comment: The most helpful info at this point would be the overview article in the documentation for extensions, which explains the basic stuff about extensions including the architecture.

Answer (score 3):

So, step by step:

- Use [`chrome.browserAction.onClicked`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#event-onClicked) to listen for the click on the extension's icon. The callback you set will be passed a reference to the Tab that was active when it was clicked.
- Get the tab's URL from [`tab.url`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#type-Tab).
- Use that original URL to generate the one you want to open, using [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with a [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) to remove the unwanted parts.
- Use [`chrome.tabs.create`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-create) to open the new tab:

Altogether, you should have this in a [background script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages):

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(tab => {
    chrome.tabs.create({ url: tab.url.replace(/new-|_owner|section-/g, '') });
});
```